# Match characters of a string in another string in the same order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching

It's kind of a basic question, but I can't find the proper answer anywhere.
I have 2 equal length strings in python and I would like to find if at least n chars (n can be any number smaller than the string length) of the first string are contained (in the same order) in the second one.

for example:

```py
s1 = 'TAGCACTTT'
s2 = 'CGATGATTT'
s3 = 'AGACGGCCT'
n = 6
```

matching s1 and s2 should return True since s2 contains the letters 'AGATTT' in order while matching s1 and s3 should return False cause only 5 letters match.
How do I do that efficiently?

Comment: What is `n` in your example ? 6? Also please add what you have tried for this question

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_sub(X, Y, m, n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0;
    elif X[m - 1] == Y[n - 1]:
        return 1 + max_sub(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1);
    else:
        return max(max_sub(X, Y, m, n - 1), max_sub(X, Y, m - 1, n))

s1 = 'TAGCACTTT'
s2 = 'CGATGATTT'
s3 = 'AGACGGCCT'
n = 6

# Permutations using library function
from itertools import permutations

# Get all permutations of [s1,s2,s3]
perm = permutations([s1, s2, s3],2)

# pass over the obtained permutations
for i in list(perm):
    len_ = max_sub(i[0], i[1], len(i[0]), len(i[1]))
    if len_ >= n:
        print("For {},{} length of common substring is: {}, True ".format(i[0], i[1], max_sub(i[0], i[1], len(i[0]), len(i[1]))))
    else:
        print("For {},{} length of common substring is: {}, False ".format(i[0], i[1], max_sub(i[0], i[1], len(i[0]), len(i[1]))))
```

output:

```
For TAGCACTTT,CGATGATTT length of common substring is: 6, True 
For TAGCACTTT,AGACGGCCT length of common substring is: 5, False 
For CGATGATTT,TAGCACTTT length of common substring is: 6, True 
For CGATGATTT,AGACGGCCT length of common substring is: 4, False 
For AGACGGCCT,TAGCACTTT length of common substring is: 5, False 
For AGACGGCCT,CGATGATTT length of common substring is: 4, False
```